# For what does "Rcon" stand for in Rijndael/AES?

Tags: aes, terminology, rijndael

How do we expand the abbreviation *“Rcon”* used in the [Rijndael key schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule)?

I know what it is, I know how it works; I just do not know for what it is a shortcut for. I mean: if "Sbox" is "Substitution box", then "Rcon" stands for… ?

Comment: All my life, I have been sure that `Rcon` means **round constant**. (But I haven't found a credible reference to back that claim so far.)

Comment: @yyyyyyy For a credible reference, check page 11 of http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [FIPS 197 (PDF)](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), on [page 11](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf#11):

> **Rcon[]**   The round constant word array.

So, the answer is obviously "**r**ound **con**stant".

Answer (score 3):

RCon == Round Constant

It's a value that slightly modifies how each round operates.  Without it, AES might be vulnerable to a (related key) [slide attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_attack).  Such an attack would probably not be of practical interest, however since it's so easy to avoid it (by including the RCon), it makes sense to.